# How can a Word writer write a manuscript with a LaTeX writer?

Tags: msword, word-to-latex

What software or tutorials are there that allow Word writers to write with LaTeX writers without Word writers having to learn LaTeX

Comment: Welcome. Word writers don't have to do anything, but then somebody else will have to do the LaTeX work. Adds quite a tension to collaborative work. Better all use the same program, hich one is a group decision.

Comment: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html)

Comment: If the document has to 'work' in Word, use Word: the LaTeX user will just have to get on with it.

Comment: The `LaTeX` author should find a more talented coauthor. ;-)

Comment: If the issue is that one co-author doesn't wish to learn LaTeX, then perhaps Lyx (https://www.lyx.org/) could be a usfeul compromise?

Comment: We've discussed this a few timesbefore; searching on "[msword]" may prove instructive, also at academia.se.

Comment: @BenK-G I strongly suspect that the co-author in question doesn't want to learn new software just to humour someone junior to them.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I've only said this in comments and never as an answer, so despite flagging as a duplicate, here's what's worked for me

I'm assuming here that there's a decent reason for the final version to use LaTeX, and that the Word-using co-author (a) is sufficiently important that you can't say "tough luck, we're doing it my way", and (b) needs to *edit* and not just *comment* on the paper.

Maintaining a Word file with LaTeX commands (`\ref{}` and `\cite{}` are probably the most important) has worked well for me in the past.  Images can be imported into Word, even equations can be compiled using `standalone` and pasted in from a parallel LaTeX document.  The body text can be converted using something like pandoc, which can deal with ordinary text quite happily including things like font formatting - though I suggest running it over a stripped down copy of your file. Word's "track changes" feature *is* useful and requires only switching on, not learning.

Comment: +1 This is a good suggestion although it will mainly work best for documents that don't depend too much on the LaTeX markup for substantial parts of the formatting. In my own field, (linguistics) for example, this won't really work since all the linguistic examples depend on markup and it would be impractical to insert each one as a standalone image. Of course you can leave that markup in but non-LaTeX users' tolerance for markup in their Word documents tends to be low.

Comment: @Alan that's true assuming that pandoc (et al.) can't handle the markup in word format. I suspect that's a good assumption. For going the other way I found custom word macros helpful, but I've had whole jobs writing ms office macros.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question before too. Some of my colleagues were much more fluent in LaTeX than I was so we tried AUTHOREA. They wrote in LaTeX and I wrote in WYSIWYG. It is web-based, like Google Docs, and you can live-collaborate with others. Offline functions are limited though. Still, it's my favorite research writing tool, you should give it a try.